# "WebTarget" vs "HttpClient.newHttpClient" for simple GET/POST

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, java-11

I currently use JEE-WebTargets in my project:

```
WebTarget target = client.target(uri);
Invocation request = target.request().buildGet();
Response resp = request.invoke();
```

Now I am considering replacing those with Java 11 `HttpClient`:

```
var httpClient = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
var request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create(uri)).build();
try {
    var resp = httpClient.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Before I go ahead I'd like to know what advantages or disadvantages there are, if there are differences in performance and what other things I should take into consideration/look out for.

Comment: Jax-RS does automatically unzip gzip compressed responses. With java-httpclient  unzip gzip compressed responses must be done manually..not very convenient..

Comment: however, using ssl and gzip is not a good idea (BREACH)..